# How to use a group by Sum SQL with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data, jpql

I want to load best seller products by quantity. These are my tables:

```
Product
id  name
1    AA   
2    BB

Productorder
order_id  product_id  quantity
1          1          10      
2          1          100    
3          2          15     
4          1          15
```

This is my Spring Data Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select top 5 p.name, sum(po.quantity) as total_quantity from product p " +
            "inner join productorder po " +
                "on p.id = po.product_id " +
            "group by p.id, p.name " +
            "order by total_quantity desc", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Product> findTopFiveBestSeller();
}
```

I am getting **HsqlException: Column not found: id**

I think this error does not have anything to do with id column, as it is there for both tables. Do "group by Sum queries" work with Spring data? Because it seems little strange for me as Spring Data should select just product attributes from the database, and with this sql we are selecting also the sum(po.quantity). Can Spring data handle this and convert the result as a List?

PS: I am using HSQLDB embedded as DB.

Comment: How could a query returning names and sums magically return a List<Product>, since a Product has an ID and a name? Your query doesn't return products, so the return type shouldn't be List<Product>

Comment: The error is likely coming from the group by, you're trying to group by p.id but it's not in your select list.

Comment: Spring has DomainClassConverter, which converts from ids concrete Objects. At least that is what i thought.. Now i changed it to "select top 5 p.*" it works... Thanks!  "select top 5 p.id" does not work though.

Comment: I added explanation to the solution, since figuring out the difference between the two queries was not trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After changing the select statements projection from `p.name` to `p.*` to indicate that I am selecting multiple values rather than just String objects that have to be magically converted to `Product` objects, this works:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select top 5 p.*, sum(po.quantity) as total_quantity from product p " +
        "inner join productorder po " +
            "on p.id = po.product_id " +
        "group by p.id, p.name " +
        "order by total_quantity desc", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Product> findTopFiveBestSeller();

}
```

Thanks @JMK und @JB Nizet.

Comment: Hi,

So did you create total_quantity  column in Product bean ? I need do similar stuff ..can you elaborate what you had in your bean level.

Comment: he can use quantity by creating an external pojo class

Comment: @TanvirChowdhury what I found is you at least have to map the column used in the SUM expression, in this case, 'quantity' I also do not return the repository object in this case. It works for me when returning List<Object[]>, with each object representing a column.

Comment: Can we achieve the same using criteria